# Finding a TraceSource from code

Tags: c#, remote-debugging, tracesource, debugview

We have a large business application which contains multiple project all managed by a single management project.

within this management project i want to adjust the switch value of certain tracesources remotly and use DebugView to see what is happening in my projects.

The only way i know i can change switch value of a tracesource WITHOUT restarting the project is to have a reference to the TraceSource and assign an new Switch.

Is it good practice to keep track of all tracesource used in my project with a static TraceSourceCollection class where the tracesources are registered or is there a better way.